# running through a loop inside a ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I managed to get the selected last value of the ListView with **getSelectedItem()**, but i cannot find out how to run through every value inside so that with **SelectionMode.MULTIPLE** i can get all the selected values.

```
listView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            label.setText(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
```

Comment: use `getSelectedItems()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

It will return a `ObservableList<T>` with all the selected items.

Comment: I noticed i probably formulated a bad question, what i want is a list or an array of some sort where i can go through every value and check if it's selected or not, and then get its text accordingly. If i return ObservableList<String> that will just return a collection of strings and i won't be able to check if selected or not. I have just started learning JavaFx so i am sorry if i am missing something

Comment: This list will return the selected elements and not all elements of the ListView.